# Unity 3D - How to use LateUpdate in Mouselook script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My build suffers from terrible stutter/lag when I cirle objects.
In this forum I have been advised to set the rigid body to "Interpolate" and to use LateUpdate in my script.

Problem is...I dont know how?
When I try, I get compiler error or just cant move the cam.

I found another free FPS script that worked, by using camera follow lag, but i cant figure out how to use that code either.

How can I use LateUpdate in my current script?

```
void Start() {
    Cursor.visible = false;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

void Update() {
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime * -1f;

    transform.Rotate(0f, x, 0f);

    headRotation += y;
    headRotation = Mathf.Clamp(headRotation, -headRotationLimit, headRotationLimit);
    cam.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(headRotation, 0f, 0f);
}
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html

Comment: I'm guessing you mean LateUpdate?

Comment: Yes sir, but when I change Update to LateUpdate the camera still do not rotate. (without stutter).

I have 500+ FPS.

Comment: `Lerp` the camera's rotation so its smoothed, but you are correct in wanting to do it in a `LateUpdate`.

Comment: How would that look in code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an edited version of my FPS player rotation method, use this as a guide for how it can be done and modify it for your needs including a couple of methods I use to limit how far the Camera can rotate (the player can look up and down)

```
// Set the Camera in the inspector so that it can be rotated
public Camera camera;


// Rotation variables for both the player and camera
private Quaternion _playerRotation;
private Quaternion _cameraRotation;

// The speed you want to be able to look
private float _lookSpeed = 3f;

// Set the initial rotations to the rotation variables
private void Awake()
{
    _playerRotation = transform.localRotation;
    _cameraRotation = camera.transform.localRotation;
}

// Method to be called from LateUpdate
private void UpdateRotation()
{
    Vector2 input = new Vector2(
        Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"),
        Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")
    );

    if (input != Vector2.zero)
    {
        _playerRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0f, _lookSpeed * input.x, 0f);
        _cameraRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(_lookSpeed * -input.y, 0f, 0f);

        _cameraRotation = ClampRotationAroundXAxis(_cameraRotation, -50f , 75f);
    }

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, _playerRotation, 10f * Time.deltaTime);
    camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(camera.transform.localRotation, _cameraRotation, 10f * Time.deltaTime);
}


// A couple of rotation methods 
// I suggest making these extensions for use anywhere in the game and for all rotations
private Quaternion ClampRotationAroundXAxis(Quaternion q, float minX = 0f, float maxX = 0f)
{
    if (q.w != 0f)
    {
        q.x /= q.w;
        q.y /= q.w;
        q.z /= q.w;
        q.w = 1f;
    }

    q.y = 0f;
    q.z = 0f;

    if (minX != 0f || maxX != 0f)
    {
        q = ClampRotationXAxis(q, minX, maxX);
    }

    return q;
}

private Quaternion ClampRotationXAxis(Quaternion q, float min, float max)
{

    if (q.w != 0f)
    {
        q.x /= q.w;
        q.y /= q.w;
        q.z /= q.w;
        q.w = 1f;
    }

    float angle = 2f * Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan(q.x);

    angle = Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);

    q.x = Mathf.Tan(0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle);

    return q;
}
```

Comment: I get compiler error with your script.

63,19 "Quaternion does not contain a definition for ClampRotationXAxis and no accessible extension method ClampRotationXAxis accepting a first argument of type Quaternion could be found".

Comment: Sorry I didn't fully remove the way I was using the `ClampRotationXAxis()` as an extension change `q.ClampRotationXAxis(minX, maxX);` to `ClampRotationXAxis(q, minX, maxX);`

Comment: Thank you for your time.

The script runs now, but i cant move camera.
I tried both attaching to the camera it self and to the player.

I might be missing something?

Comment: These methods would go in script you use for the rest of your player controls on the player, and did you add a call to the rotation method in the `LateUpdate`?

Comment: OK, I will try and play around with it.
My coding skills are pretty basic.
Thank you.